# Update DLL used by a SSIS on server

Tags: dll, ssis

I developed a dll used by a SSIS to be able to perform web api call.
This dll is registered with regasm and gacutil to be able to use it with the task script in the SSIS.
I updated the dll, I deployed it and register the new version with regasm and gacutil.
When I run the SSIS, the result still the same as the old version of the dll. So I presume that the dll still loaded in the memory.

In the server, I already stop/start the services SQL Server and SQL Server Agent but I still have the issue.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Search where else the DLL went. Likely you will find it also somewhere close to the SSIS binaries (which is bizarre). Most probably this will be the DLL SSIS **actually** uses.

Comment: Try gacutil –u <assembly name> to remove assembly from GAC and see if your task will fail.

Answer (score 0):

When looking into my old deployment code I always removed old version from GAC using:

```
(path)\bin\gacutil.exe –u assembly_name
(path)\bin\gacutil.exe –i assembly_file_name
```

If it is a custom component, I copied the dll to (SQLServerpath)\DTS\PipelineComponents